# Taronga and Werribee – a cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/yraonp68)

**Across**
1. Did parrot on record ignore instrument backer? (4)
4. For one grand prize, an everyday kitchen item (6)
10. Male bits set on fire with bits of oil and low sugar alcohol (7)
12. Two people are in fact in the red, according to auditor (3)
13. Before dark Brown University is ready for action (6)
14. Network unavailable to back up record (5)
15. Earn $1,000 on board very small spacecraft (1-5)
17. Thorough cleaning! (P.S. Sanitise wound) (10)
20. Just about anyone: "Quebec watering hole has restroom at the front – and no end to vermin!" (4,1,6)
22. Given too much juice and beaten? (11)
25. Former premier of Umbria stopped (when Italy reformed) being ace (10)
28. Destroying Dan's kitchen drinking port (6)
31. Laws broken to hide heroin? One may be involved in a cover-up (5)
33. Church is circled by creature with sharp teeth and hairy tail that's like an earworm (6)
34. Coward retreats, abandoning line for a long time (3)
35. Destroy this piece of jewellery to get angrier? (7)
36. Andrew's work involved backing Edward's trainees (6)
37. Leader leaves foundation unaltered (2,2)

**Down**
1. Rose admits "one on one" is a type of symmetry (5)
2. East Siberian flower for woman (5)
3. Is queen cross after decision at the front to relinquish territory? (8)
5. The word is the Republicans assumed control of revolutionary multinational collaboration project (6)
6. Empty condo King invited all of us in, showing sign that there hasn't been anyone home for a while (6)
7. Universal Soldier holds large tangelo (4)
8. "Crosspiece", it's called (4)
9. Dessert is what's depicted on some warning signs along roads in the north, reportedly (6)
11. Endlessly spreading falsehoods is characteristically negative (3)
16. Accordingly, Australia's upcoming examples include Taronga and Werribee (4)
18. Abundance of the polar storms (8)
19. Killed or thrown into the cooler? (4)
21. Rocky old rocker finally rocked (not having rocked initially) (6)
23. Perhaps Soviet gets American cabinet ultimately in a visible state of decay (6)
24. No principals hold that to be very familiar (3,3)
26. It marks the spot in the middle of ground – I say it goes straight up (1-4)
27. Fringe elements to fail to meet silver screen's top standards (5)
29. Christian, me and Oscar drive around (4)
30. Picked up someone dozing valley in California (4)
32. Bring up present that's ready for Dear Leader? (3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Another great pangram-style cryptic crossword from @Jafe - congratulations on this being your 500th puzzle post on PSE!*

The completed grid looks like this:

> [image: Completed grid]

Clue explanations:

> **Across:**
>  1. **Did parrot** on record ignore instrument backer? (4) **APED** = (-t)APED (on record, ignoring (-instrumen)T)
>  4. For one grand prize, **an everyday kitchen item** (6) **EGGCUP** = E.G. (For one) + G (grand) + CUP (prize)
>  10. Male bits set on fire with bits of oil and low **sugar alcohol** (7) **[XYLITOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylitol)** = XY (Male bits, i.e. the chromosomes) + LIT + O(-il) + L(-ow)
>  12. **Two people** are in fact in the red, according to auditor (3) **DUO** = “do owe”
>  13. Before dark Brown University is **ready for action** (6) **USABLE** = U (University) + SABLE (dark brown)
>  14. Network unavailable to back up **record** (5) **ANNAL** = (LAN (Network) + NA (unavailable))<
>  15. Earn \$1,000 on board very small spacecraft (1-5) **[X-WINGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-wing_fighter)** = WIN (Earn) + G (\$1,000) all in XS (very small)
>  17. **Thorough cleaning!** (P.S. Sanitise wound) (10) **ANTISEPSIS** = PSSANITISE*
>  20. **Just about anyone:** "Quebec watering hole has restroom at the front – and no end to vermin!" (4,1,6) **JOHN Q PUBLIC** = JOHN (restroom) + Q (Quebec) + PUB (Watering hole) + LIC(-e)
>  22. **Given too much juice** and **beaten**? (11) **OVERPOWERED** = ddef
>  25. Former premier of Umbria stopped (when Italy reformed) being **ace** (10) **ASEXUALITY** = EX + U(-mbria) all in between AS (when) and ITALY*
>  28. Destroying Dan's kitchen drinking **port** (6) **GDANSK** = _G DANS K_
>  31. Laws broken to hide heroin? **One may be involved in a cover-up** (5) = **SHAWL** = H (heroin) in LAWS*
>  33. Church is circled by creature with sharp teeth and hairy tail that's **like an earworm** (6) **CATCHY** = CAT (creature with sharp teeth) + CH (church) + (-hair)Y
>  34. Coward retreats, abandoning line for **a long time** (3) **EON** = [NOE(-l)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No%C3%ABl_Coward)<
>  35. Destroy **this piece of jewellery** to get angrier? (7) **EARRING** = ANGRIER* (cdef)
>  36. Andrew's work involved backing Edward's **trainees** (6) **CADETS** = [CATS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cats_(musical)) around ED<
>  37. Leader leaves foundation **unaltered** (2,2) **AS IS** = (-b)ASIS
>
>  **Down:**
>  1. Rose admits "one on one" is a type of symmetry (5) **AXIAL** = AX(I + A)L where “one” is I and also A, and “Rose” is [AXL Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axl_Rose)
>  2. East Siberian flower for **woman** (5) **ELENA** = E (East) + [LENA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lena_(river)) (Siberian flow-er)
>  3. Is queen cross after decision at the front to **relinquish territory**? (8) **DISANNEX** = D(-ecision) + IS + [ANNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne,_Queen_of_Great_Britain) (queen) + X (cross)
>  5. **The word is** the Republicans assumed control of revolutionary multinational collaboration project (6) **GOSSIP** = [GOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republican_Party_(United_States)) (the Republicans) around [ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station)< (multinational collaboration project)
>  6. Empty condo King invited all of us in, showing **sign that there hasn't been anyone home for a while** (6) **COBWEB** = C(-ond)O + WE (all of us) in [BB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._B._King) (King)
>  7. Universal Soldier holds large **tangelo** (4) **UGLI** = U (Universal) + L (large) in GI (soldier)
>  8. "**Crosspiece**", it's **called** (4) **RUNG** = ddef
>  9. **Dessert** is what's depicted on some warning signs along roads in the north, reportedly (6) **MOUSSE** = “moose”
>  11. Endlessly spreading falsehoods is **characteristically negative** (3) **[YIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang)** = (-l)YIN(-g)
>  16. Accordingly, Australia's upcoming **examples include [Taronga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taronga_Zoo) and [Werribee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werribee_Open_Range_Zoo)** (4) **ZOOS** = (SO (accordingly) + OZ (Australia))<
>  18. **Abundance** of the polar storms (8) **PLETHORA** = THEPOLAR*
>  19. **Killed** or **thrown into the cooler**? (4) **ICED** = ddef
>  21. **Rocky** old rocker finally rocked (not having rocked initially) (6) **JAGGED** = [JAGGE(-r)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mick_Jagger) (old rocker, not having R(-ocked)) + (-rocke)D
>  23. Perhaps Soviet gets American cabinet ultimately **in a visible state of decay** (6) **RUSTED** = US (American) + (-cabine)T all in RED (Perhaps Soviet)
>  24. No principals hold that to be **very familiar** (3,3) **OLD HAT** = (-h)OLD (-t)HAT
>  26. It marks the spot in the middle of ground – I say **it goes straight up** (1-4) **Y-AXIS** = X in ISAY*
>  27. Fringe elements to fail to meet silver screen's top **standards** (5) **FLAGS** = F(-ai)L + Ag (silver) + S(-creen)
>  29. **Christian**, me and Oscar drive around (4) **[DIOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Dior)** = I (me) + O (Oscar) all in DR (drive)
>  30. Picked up someone dozing **valley in California** (4) **[NAPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napa_Valley_AVA)** = “napper”
>  32. Bring up present that's **ready for Dear Leader?** (3) **WON** (currency of [North Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Jong_Il)) = NOW<

Comment: Nice! For 15A, rot13(V guvax [I-Jvatf](https://www.starwars.com/databank/v-wing-fighter) vf nyfb cbffvoyr, jvgu i sbe irel naq f sbe fznyy?)

Comment: @oAlt That's actually what my first answer for that question was! However, I didn't get the answer check complete on penpa and knew something somewhere must be wrong (or unintended). It needed the 'X' to pass the checker :)